# how to set customize delimiter in vue-cli 3?

Tags: django, vue-cli-3

I'm using django with vue-cli 3 and I want to access the django data in vue template but there is a conflict with the syntax of data accessing i.e. delimiter in case of vue. Now I want to resolve this issue but the delimiter option is not working or I don't know where or how to add this command. I tried to add this to the main.js file in the src directory but it did not work out. Please suggest me if you know the solution or have any solution.

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding delimiters in Vue 3 is almost similar to Vue 2.

```js
const SomeFeature = {
    delimiters: ['${', '}$'],
    data () {
        return {}
    }
}

Vue.createApp(SomeFeature).mount("#app")
```

Reference: [Delimiters in Vue 3](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#delimiters)